# Why I am getting failed to resolve module specifier error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, module, firebase-authentication

My JS Code(Firebase):

```
<script type="module">
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
     
      import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
      import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged,createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
      import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
       //app config
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
      const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    </script>
```

My Script file for authentication:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';




console.log("helossssss");

let signupbtn = document.querySelector('.signupbtn');
signupbtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    // e.preventDefault();
    let email = document.querySelector('#newuseremail');
    let password = document.querySelector('#newuserpassword');
    console.log("Heelo World")

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            let user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user);
            email.value = "";
            password.value = "";
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
})
```

I am getting this error repeatedly:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/auth". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I have already referred to the docs for upgradation from compat code to modular code:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat

But that doesn't seem to resolve my problem.

Comment: did you try to import createUserWithEmailAndPassword in any way that error suggests? like from '/firebase/auth' ./firebase/auth' etc?

Comment: 'firebase/compat/auth'; maybe a solution as well. I remember it helped once

Comment: @DenizKaradağ I tried both the things but none of them worked.